# Is use_dimred deprecated or is this a runTSNE() bug?

Tags: single-cell, tsne

NOTE: I posted the same question on [Biostars](https://www.biostars.org/p/9507222/) but so far no replies there so I figured I would ask here, too.

So, I was running a pipeline which I developed some time ago and a very weird behaviour was found, which had quite an impact over our analyses.

Indeed, the scater's runTSNE() function was subjected to a change in the parameters names and, in particular, the old use_dimred parameter now has a new name, which is dimred.

Interestingly, I was running the pipeline using the runTSNE() function and passing the dimensionality reduction through use_dimred which is apparently deprecated and obtaining very weird results without being aware of that since no warning and/or error was returned.

A quick example:

```
# load some data
library("scRNAseq")
library("scater")
sce.416b <- LunSpikeInData(which="416b")
```

check the data and notice no dimensionality reduction is available:

```
> sce.416b
class: SingleCellExperiment 
dim: 46604 192 
metadata(0):
assays(1): counts
rownames(46604): ENSMUSG00000102693 ENSMUSG00000064842 ...
  ENSMUSG00000095742 CBFB-MYH11-mcherry
rowData names(1): Length
colnames(192): SLX-9555.N701_S502.C89V9ANXX.s_1.r_1
  SLX-9555.N701_S503.C89V9ANXX.s_1.r_1 ...
  SLX-11312.N712_S508.H5H5YBBXX.s_8.r_1
  SLX-11312.N712_S517.H5H5YBBXX.s_8.r_1
colData names(9): Source Name cell line ... spike-in addition block
reducedDimNames(0):            <-- HERE IT IS EMPTY
mainExpName: endogenous
altExpNames(2): ERCC SIRV
```

at this point I simply run the runTSNE() function using a non-existent dimred:

```
# set seed
set.seed(001)
# add logcounts
sce.416b <- logNormCounts(sce.416b)
# add random colours to cells
colLabels(sce.416b) <- rep(c(1,2,3,4), 48)
# runTSNE, first try
sce.416b <- runTSNE(sce.416b, use_dimred="made_up_dimred", perplexity=30)
# and plot
dev.new(); plotTSNE(sce.416b, colour_by="label")
# runTSNE, second try
sce.416b <- runTSNE(sce.416b, use_dimred="another_made_up_dimred", perplexity=30)
# and plot
dev.new(); plotTSNE(sce.416b, colour_by="label")
# runTSNE, third try
sce.416b <- runTSNE(sce.416b, use_dimred="a_third_made_up_dimred", perplexity=30)
# and plot
dev.new(); plotTSNE(sce.416b, colour_by="label")
```

it, unfortunately, works. Indeed, I now have three TSNE available that I did plot and that are slightly different with each other.

```
> sce.416b
class: SingleCellExperiment 
dim: 46604 192 
metadata(0):
assays(2): counts logcounts
rownames(46604): ENSMUSG00000102693 ENSMUSG00000064842 ...
  ENSMUSG00000095742 CBFB-MYH11-mcherry
rowData names(1): Length
colnames(192): SLX-9555.N701_S502.C89V9ANXX.s_1.r_1
  SLX-9555.N701_S503.C89V9ANXX.s_1.r_1 ...
  SLX-11312.N712_S508.H5H5YBBXX.s_8.r_1
  SLX-11312.N712_S517.H5H5YBBXX.s_8.r_1
colData names(10): Source Name cell line ... block sizeFactor
reducedDimNames(1): TSNE      <-- THERE YOU GO: A NICE TSNE COMPUTED OVER A NON-EXISTENT DIMRED
mainExpName: endogenous
altExpNames(2): ERCC SIRV
```

What is even more interesting is that if I run the function with the newly renamed parameter, i.e. dimred, I do get an error:

```
> sce.416b <- runTSNE(sce.416b, dimred="made_up_dimred", perplexity=30)
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : 
  invalid subscript 'type' in 'reducedDim(<SingleCellExperiment>, type="character", ...)':
  'made_up_dimred' not in 'reducedDimNames(<SingleCellExperiment>)'
```

But then, if you have an old pipeline which used the runTSNE function with the use_dimred and you're now running an updated version of scater, I have no idea what you may get.

So, as per my question...is this a bug? Has anyone else noticed this weird behaviour? Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it would be easier to answer the question by dividing it into related but more specific questions. Having said that, even if the answers below would be satisfactory, I would still post this on the package's Github repo, the author being informed about this can help other users of this package.

Question 1: Why does `runTSNE()` work when I use the deprecated `use_dimred` argument?

Let's create function and call it:

```
> my_func <- function(dimred) {
+   if(missing(dimred)) {
+     print("dimred argument is not provided so something else is being done...")
+   } else {
+     print(dimred)
+   }
+ }
> my_func(42)
[1] 42
> my_func(dimred = 42)
[1] 42
> my_func()
[1] "dimred argument is not provided so something else is being done..."
> my_func(use_dimred = 42)
Error in my_func(use_dimred = 42) : unused argument (use_dimred = 42)
```

As expected, we get an error if we call a function with an argument that does not belong to our function: `use_dimread`. If we define our function with the special argument `...` however, it works:

```
> my_func <- function(dimred, ...) {
+   if(missing(dimred)) {
+     print("dimred argument is not provided so something else is being done...")
+   } else {
+     print(dimred)
+   }
+ }
> my_func(42)
[1] 42
> my_func(dimred = 42)
[1] 42
> my_func()
[1] "dimred argument is not provided so something else is being done..."
> my_func(use_dimred = 42)
[1] "dimred argument is not provided so something else is being done..."
```

Basically when you call a function, the function you are calling can make calls to other functions and the `...` is basically allowing the user to feed arguments for these let's say "secondary" functions. Apparently `R` does not care if what you feed as an argument to a function is used or not if the function is defined with the special `...` argument.

Question 2: Why is `runTSNE()` working if the supplied `use_dimred` argument was not used (as shown above)?

If you take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/Alanocallaghan/scater/blob/RELEASE_3_12/R/runTSNE.R), `calculateTSNE()`, which `runTSNE()` runs under the hood, is using PCA if the `dimred` argument is not provided, its default is NULL anyway. It is been a while since I have used `Scater` but I think this would mean that the tSNE is being computed on (some number of) PCs.

And as a conclusion, I don't think we can really call this a bug but a rather unexpected behavior because of use of the special `...` argument in the function definition.

Comment: well, this is definitely interesting. I did not consider the implications of using the `...`. I will let the developers know for sure.